# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on API 17 in Android Studio

Tags: android, fragment, android-recyclerview, fragmentpageradapter

App is working well on API 22,23 but unfortunately when I tried on API 17 it crashes and through the error as shown below

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.trueblueoperator.swachhapp.FragmentAllStory
      at com.trueblueoperator.swachhapp.TabPagerAdapter.getItem(TabPagerAdapter.java:20)
```

Here is my TabPagerAdapter.java code

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return new FragmentAllStory();
        case 1:
            return new FragmentActions();
        case 2:
            return new FragmentIdeas();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Stories";
        case 1:
            return "Actions";
        case 2:
            return "Ideas";
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
}
```

And FragmentAllStory.java file code

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FragmentAllStory extends Fragment implements RecyclerView.OnScrollChangeListener {

//Creating a List of superheroes
private List<AllStoryData> allStoryDataList;

//Volley Request Queue
private RequestQueue requestQueue;

private Boolean orientation = true;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
//The request counter to send ?page=1, ?page=2  requests
private int requestCount = 1;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestCount = 1;
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_story, container, false);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    recyclerView = new RecyclerView(getActivity());
    if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, 1));
    }
    else {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, 1));
    }
    allStoryDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    getData();
    recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(this);
    adapter = new AllStoryAdapter(allStoryDataList, getActivity());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return recyclerView;
}
@Override
public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
    //Ifscrolled at last then

}
}
```

Thanks for the time.

Comment: Older versions of software (API 17 in this case) sometimes do not have the same functionalities as newer (API 22,23 in this case).

Comment: so what would i do for getting it work on older devices also, any alternate way so that i can also use the newer functionalities for latest API's as well as the older way for older API's inside the same APP

Comment: Could you please post the import headers for each class? Also your gradle file

Comment: Package the API with you app, however this can lead to issues with APIs used by this API. So the usual end result is: Code for the older version or disable certain functionality in older versions.

Comment: #breakline I have edited the code with import headers

Comment: #Norbert Will plz give me an sample example that ow i will do it inside a single app (i.e. disabling certain functionality or adding older functionalities for the perticular API's)